# How can I use a library that calls xmlhttprequest in node.js?

Tags: node.js, odata

I would like to run tests of OData interfaces from node.js, using the data.js library. Unfortunately, data.js is intended for use in browsers and uses XMLHttpRequest calls. node.js cannot handle such calls because, I believe, they are implemented in the browser, not in JavaScript. Is there a module that will let me use data.js in node.js?

The usual solutions for XMLHttpRequest are OK when you can call them in your own code, but here I don't want to change data.js, so those options are not open.

Here is a sample of what goes wrong:

```
var odata = require("./datajs-1.1.0.js");
try{
    odata.OData.read( 
        "http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories" 
    );
}
catch(err){
    console.log ("Exception in index.js - " + err.name + ": " + err.message);
}
```

Running `node.js index.js`:

```
Exception in index.js - undefined: XMLHttpRequest not supported
```

Comment: did you ever get this working?  I have the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I moved on to other projects and this one was left by the side of the road. Best of luck in your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

The exception may be a result of requiring the datajs library with a file system literal ("./") instead of as a node_module (which would be more along the lines of require("datajs")). The latter normally requires use of npm (it stands for node packaged modules), and you would want to run the following command in your project directory:

```
npm install datajs
```

The reference page for the datajs library can be found at https://npmjs.org/package/datajs.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Sandile. I've given that a go and no luck. For some reason I get a warning on installing datajs, and then node says "Cannot find module datajs.js".  The warning is: npm WARN package.json datajs@1.0.3 No repository field.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that, npm install xmlhttprequest (or similar). That module has issues with escaping... Or you can use jaydata which just works

Comment: Thanks Gabor. I don't think xmlhttprequest will work, as the call is not in my code (it's in datajs) and I'd rather not go editing that. My understanding is that the xmlhttprequest package does not cover that case? I am investigating jaydata...